# Itext HtmlConverter.convertToPdf is slow in converting the html to pdf

Tags: pdf, java-8, itext, pdf-generation

I have a requirement to convert HTML to PDF in real time. For the same i'm using IText.

```
        PdfDocument inputDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(byteArrayOutputStream))) {
      String html = "<html><head><Title> My pdf</Title></head></html>";
      inputDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, new PdfHeaderHandler(pageNumber,
          pageCount));
      inputDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new PdfFooterHandler(pageNumber,
          pageCount));

      HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), inputDoc,
          converterProperties);
      return new PdfDocument(
          new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray())));
    } catch (IOException exception) {
      getLogger().error("Html to Pdf conversion failed for page {} of {} due to error {}", pageNumber, pageCount,
          exception.getMessage());
    }
```

Now the problem is if the number pages are in the range of 30-50 and even if i'm converting each html page in parallel with 20 threads, i can see huge turnaround time, in range from 5-10 seconds per page.

One such example with 19 page and 20 threads, logs mentioned below:

```
2020-06-19 14:54:12.730 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-12] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Converting PDF for page 3
2020-06-19 14:54:12.731 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-5] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Converting PDF for page 2
2020-06-19 14:54:12.736 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-6] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Converting PDF for page 4
2020-06-19 14:54:12.754 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-19] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Converting PDF for page 5
2020-06-19 14:54:12.793 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-15] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Converting PDF for page 7
2020-06-19 14:54:12.793 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-10] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Converting PDF for page 6
2020-06-19 14:54:12.798 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-14] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Converting PDF for page 9
2020-06-19 14:54:12.798 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-16] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Converting PDF for page 8
2020-06-19 14:54:12.798 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-7] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Converting PDF for page 10
2020-06-19 14:54:12.802 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-4] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Converting PDF for page 11
2020-06-19 14:54:12.805 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-17] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Converting PDF for page 12
2020-06-19 14:54:12.807 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-8] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Converting PDF for page 13
2020-06-19 14:54:12.808 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-3] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Converting PDF for page 14
2020-06-19 14:54:12.811 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-1] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Converting PDF for page 15
2020-06-19 14:54:12.813 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-2] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Converting PDF for page 16
2020-06-19 14:54:12.815 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-9] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Converting PDF for page 17
2020-06-19 14:54:12.817 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-11] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Converting PDF for page 18
2020-06-19 14:54:12.819 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-13] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Converting PDF for page 19
2020-06-19 14:54:12.820 [qtp403879268-30] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Waiting for futures to complete
2020-06-19 14:54:12.830 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-20] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Converting PDF for page 1
2020-06-19 14:54:20.398 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-6] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Done converting PDF for page 4
2020-06-19 14:54:20.416 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-11] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Done converting PDF for page 18
2020-06-19 14:54:20.428 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-13] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Done converting PDF for page 19
2020-06-19 14:54:20.458 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-19] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Done converting PDF for page 5
2020-06-19 14:54:20.488 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-12] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Done converting PDF for page 3
2020-06-19 14:54:20.633 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-4] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Done converting PDF for page 11
2020-06-19 14:54:20.802 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-14] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Done converting PDF for page 9
2020-06-19 14:54:20.905 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-8] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Done converting PDF for page 13
2020-06-19 14:54:20.913 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-17] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Done converting PDF for page 12
2020-06-19 14:54:21.095 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-7] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Done converting PDF for page 10
2020-06-19 14:54:21.144 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-10] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Done converting PDF for page 6
2020-06-19 14:54:21.244 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-15] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Done converting PDF for page 7
2020-06-19 14:54:21.293 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-20] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Done converting PDF for page 1
2020-06-19 14:54:21.327 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-1] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Done converting PDF for page 15
2020-06-19 14:54:21.329 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-16] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Done converting PDF for page 8
2020-06-19 14:54:21.335 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-3] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Done converting PDF for page 14
2020-06-19 14:54:21.360 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-9] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Done converting PDF for page 17
2020-06-19 14:54:21.384 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-2] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Done converting PDF for page 16
2020-06-19 14:54:21.404 [PdfGenerationThreadPoolExecutor-5] INFO  c.p.s.a.s.d.s.i.PdfGenerationService - Done converting PDF for page 2
```

If you notice for each page it is taking ~8s and we wish to bring it down significantly.

Can somebody suggest any improvement or any alternative libraries which will be helpful for us.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Antariksh, your logs shows the use of `Futures`, your code doesn't. Could you show how you call your code with `Futures`?

Comment: Ali Bdeir, are you really interested in this specific way of using `HtmlConverter` in parallel with `Futures`?

Comment: @mkl The problem is that HtmlConverter.ToPdf is highly inefficient and takes nearly 10 seconds per page. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @AliBdeir *"takes nearly 10 seconds per page"* - if I read the log file excerpt in the question text correctly, Antariksh's parallelized test code in 10 seconds produced 20 PDF pages.

Comment: When it comes to optimization, all circumstances have to be taken into account. So did you measure the example code you wrote in the question as well? (Where e.g. reading the input doesn't need significant time, and is quite unrealistic.) Also please note that the time it takes to render HTML into a PDF also will heavily depend on the actual contents of the HTML.

Comment: Also please specify which iText version you are using

Comment: I just tried hard to reproduce your example somehow, but the code fragment is really broken. Please "upgrade" it to a [mre] if you expect useful help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to wrap CLI tools in Java, you could use [`wkhtmltopdf`](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/), it's written in C++ so it should be much faster.

There are [premade wrappings available](https://github.com/jhonnymertz/java-wkhtmltopdf-wrapper) too.

Other than that, I don't think there are many competitors in terms of speed in Java.

`OpenPDF` is just a fork of IText, with similar performance presumably.